# Ansible lists from json file

Tags: json, ansible

via ansible I need to parse a JSON file and based on the contents, running some kind of commands on a linux system.
I worked to manage everything except Disk section, I'm still stuck at it. This is the JSON ( I share few lines )

```
[
    {
        "Hostname": "cavia",
        "Farm": "paolo",
    "Cluster": "paperino",
        "Gateway":  "10.14.35.1",
    "Dns": "172.26.5.110,172.26.5.111,172.26.16.11,172.26.16.12",
    "Routes": "0",
        "Network": [
            {
                "MAC":"00:50:56:b6:c0:db",
                "Vlan":"107 - 10.14.8.0/24 - BE WW TF",
                "Scope": "Production",
                "IP": "10.14.35.9",
                "MASK": "255.255.255.224"
            },
            {
                "MAC":"50:56:b6:19:0c",
                "Vlan":"5 - 10.4.81.0/24 - BE WW TF",
                "Scope": "BE",
                "IP": "10.4.5.9",
                "MASK": "255.255.255.224"
            },
            {
                "MAC":"00:50:56:b6:19:aa",
                "Vlan":"4 - 0.14.81.0/24 - BE WW TF",
                "Scope": "NFS",
                "IP": "172.10.0.5",
                "MASK": "255.255.0.0"
            },
            {
                "MAC":"00:50:b6:19:0c",
                "Vlan":"10087 - 10.14.81.0/24 - BE WW TF",
                "Scope": "Backup",
                "IP": "10.4.96.28",
                "MASK": "255.255.254.0"
            }
        ],   
        "Disk": [
            {
                "ID": "36000c29ccb2f18976786181535e88772",
                "Scope": "New",
                "DiskFs": "/prova"
            },
            {
                "ID": "36000c29ccb2f18976786181535e86553",
                "Scope": "New",
                "DiskFs": "/pippo"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is what I wrote in the playbook:

```
---
- name: "Phase 4 : Filesystem Configuration"
  hosts: just_parsed
  vars:
    data: "{{ lookup('file', '../data/data.json') }}"
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:


    - set_fact:
        disklen: "{{ data[0].Disk | length }}"


    - debug:
        msg: "disklen length is {{ disklen }}"

    - name: Collecting mapped disks
      set_fact:
        localdisks: "{{ ansible_devices.keys() | select('match','sd+') | list }}"



    - debug:
        var: localdisks
```

I need to:
1) Looking for the Disk.ID over `ansible_devices.<disk>.links.ids.scsi-<id>`. For example, taking sdb disk from ansible_devices:

```
"sdb": {
            "holders": [], 
            "host": "Serial Attached SCSI controller: VMware PVSCSI SCSI Controller (rev 02)", 
            "links": {
                "ids": [
                    "scsi-36000c293b2abdd05935792f86fa53bb9", 
                    "wwn-0x6000c293b2abdd05935792f86fa53bb9"
                ], 
                "labels": [], 
                "masters": [], 
                "uuids": []
            }, 
            "model": "Virtual disk", 
            "partitions": {
                "sdb1": {
                    "holders": [
                        "vgvar-lvvar"
                    ], 
                    "links": {
                        "ids": [
                            "lvm-pv-uuid-lOyio6-WTDV-vcQx-CE2h-TbZk-zsH0-HuMqIc", 
                            "scsi-36000c293b2abdd05935792f86fa53bb9-part1", 
                            "wwn-0x6000c293b2abdd05935792f86fa53bb9-part1"
                        ], 
                        "labels": [], 
                        "masters": [
                            "dm-3"
                        ], 
                        "uuids": []
                    }, 
                    "sectors": "20971519", 
                    "sectorsize": 512, 
                    "size": "10.00 GB", 
                    "start": "1", 
                    "uuid": null
                }
            }
```

I should see if one of the ID from the json file match `ansible_devices.sdb.links.ids.scsi-36000c293b2abdd05935792f86fa53bb9` but they are 2 loops, one from the ID and one from ansible_devices.
Do you have any suggestion to compare these elements?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task below probably does the job (given the JSON data are stored in *hw_info*).

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.0.dev }} mounted to device {{ item.1.dev }}"
  loop: "{{ hw_info.0.Disk|
            json_query('[].{dev: DiskFs, id: ID}')|
            product(
            ansible_facts.devices|dict2items|
            json_query('[].{dev: key, ids: value.links.ids}'))|
            list }}"
  when: item.1.ids|map('search', item.0.id) is any
```

---

To debug the filter take a look at the lists which are used in the [product](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#product-filters) filter.

```
- debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ hw_info.0.Disk|
            json_query('[].{dev: DiskFs, id: ID}') }}"

- debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ ansible_facts.devices|dict2items|
            json_query('[].{dev: key, ids: value.links.ids}') }}"
```

---

> Q: *I should execute this only when the scope is "New"*

A: Add the `scope` item into the dictionary and use it in the *when* condition. For example

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.0.dev }} mounted to device {{ item.1.dev }}"
  loop: "{{ hw_info.0.Disk|
            json_query('[].{dev: DiskFs, id: ID, scope: Scope}')|
            product(
            ansible_facts.devices|dict2items|
            json_query('[].{dev: key, ids: value.links.ids}'))|
            list }}"
  when:
    - item.1.ids|map('search', item.0.id) is any
    - item.0.scope == "New"
```

Comment: Hello Vladimir, thank you again for your time!It works but I have to go deep and understand HOW, because I'm not lazy.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion about the "New" scope? I should execute this only when the scope is "New". I don't think to change the loop, but adding a condition to when. Product filter is awesome but a bit handsome

Comment: Sure. It's pretty straightforward. I've added the example.

Comment: so the key is still item.0, very impressive!!

Comment: Sorry but it is failing.. ehehe, the scope I'm looking for is from json file, if you see Disk [] has an element called Scope. It should be something like Disk[i].Scope == "New" but it should be a new loop?

Comment: Open a new question. It's not possible to proceed with comments here.